# Not destroying objects fast enough and causing another collision

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision-detection, collider

I have a detection if a bullet hits an enemy that's part of a script that's on an enemy:

```
void OnTriggerEnter (Collider other)
{
    if (other.tag == "Bullet") {
        Destroy (other); // or Destroy (other, 0);
    }
}
```

The problem is when a bullet hits an enemy, its health drops to zero (from 100) as if it was hit more than once (I also checked with Debug.log).

So is there a way to make the bullet to destroy faster so it won't trigger again?

Also, should this detection script be on the enemy or on the bullet?

Comment: instead of Destroy(other) use Destroy(other.gameObject). other is just a collider reference not the actual gameObject itself.

Comment: Post the `TakeDamage` function. Also, use `Debug.Log` to check how many times `OnTriggerEnter` is called. @deepankar You should post that as an answer as that's likely the problem

Comment: @Programmer `TakeDamage` is really not interesting, the same happens even when I remove that call. I added debug.log and it enters twice, even with `Destroy(other.gameObject)`.

Comment: I know this is solved but `TakeDamage` function is important here because you complained about score dropping to zero (from 100). I don't know why you would remove it. By showing us the function we can use process of elimination(including `Debug.Log`) to find your issue.

Comment: It was noise, the problem was that it entered `OnTriggerEnter` twice. @Programmer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `Destroy(other)` use `Destroy(other.gameObject)`. other is just a collider reference not the actual gameObject itself.

Also just for good practice instead of comparing tag with == use `other.CompareTag(String tagName)`. Its less memory consuming.

Comment: Have you attached two colliders to your bullet object. Or Are you sure there is just one bullet hitting the enemy. You can print InstanceId, and check if they are same or different.

Comment: use collider.gameObject.GetInstanceID() to get uniqueId

Comment: It had two colliders. Thanks.